# Is is possible to delete a postbin.org bin?

Tags: webhooks

I created a test postbin.org bin to handle some webhook testing.

Is there a way to delete this bin so it's no longer accessable?

Nothing sensitive was posted to it, but I'd like to remove it all the same if that's possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to e-mail an admin.

proNOSPAMgriNOSPAMum@gmaNOSPAMil.com

Do remove the NOSPAM, obviously!

Comment: Jeff was nice enough to honor my request. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> If over 10MB of data is posted in a day, this bin will be deleted.

So just do that :)